# How to deep copy (clone) HttpServletRequest?

Tags: java, jetty

How I can deep copy (Clone) HttpServletRequest in java. As I know it is neither Serializable nor Cloneable. I found some code in internet suggested using of HttpServletRequestWrapper but actually when I used it I realized it is doing shallow copy not deep copy. I appreciate any solution for simply duplicating/ Cloning or deep copying of HttpServletRequest. I know it is not a good idea to do it but I have encountered a scenario in which if I don't clone it then I need to do more refactors on the code and revising many unit tests.

Comment: Refer to this article: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-reading-httpservletrequest-multiple-times
Just wrap all requests with filter and all classes which read request body in any way will use cached body data.

Comment: I could not read request parameters after the body is read, so I had to cache parameter map when instantiating.

Answer (score 2):

> I know it is not a good idea to do it but I have encountered a scenario in which if I don't clone it then I need to do more refactors on the code and revising many unit tests.

Please, be advised, that rigid tests are a sign of improper testing and are a problem in and of themselves. They will cause many troubles, including troubles with refactoring, which you experience now, when you can't achieve your goal. The tests hold you back, because they were improperly written, to such a degree that you no longer see refactor as a viable solution. The best thing you should do, is update your tests so that refactors like that are possible.

As to the cloning, instances of this class were not meant to be cloned or copied, you will run into more problems trying to do this than you have now, and at least now you know what your problems are (unit tests and refactoring). The things that could happen with semi-cloned HttpRequest accessed from multiple threads would make you say `should have just fixed those tests back then`.